# ¿Can I change the PGID of new bash instances?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, process, pid

I am writting a bash script first.sh in which I am required to run another scrip second.sh as a daemon.

In order to do so it must be launched from a new bash instance using nohup, so when the bash instance ends second.sh will be adopted by systemd.

How can it be implemented?
Is there a way that the next bash instances launched from first.sh will have a different pgid than the one of second.sh?

bash -c 'nohup second.sh &'>/dev/null
When new bash instances are launched, the first one shares the pgid of second.sh, is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

In bash, use `set -m` on, new processes will be spawned in a new process group:

```
(set -m; exec new_process_in_new_group)
```

You can also use [`setsid`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setsid.1.html) but this starts a new session, which includes a new process group amongst others.